# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have these two methods:

```
@api.multi
def new_open_window(self, list_ids, xml_id, module): 
    """ Generate new window at view form or tree
    """
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    act_obj = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
    result = mod_obj._get_id(module, xml_id) 
    imd_id = mod_obj.browse(result, ['res_id'])
    result = act_obj.browse(imd_id) 
    result['res_id'] = list_ids
    return result

@api.multi
def create_invoice(self): 
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    #context = context or {}
    wizard_brw = self.browse() 
    inv_id = self._context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise UserError(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id) 
        else:
            raise UserError(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window([inv_id],
                                'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

These methods were originally like this (on v8):

```
    def new_open_window(self, cr, uid, ids, list_ids, xml_id, module,
                    context=None):
    """ Generate new window at view form or tree
    """
    mod_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    act_obj = self.pool.get('ir.actions.act_window')
    result = mod_obj._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)
    imd_id = mod_obj.read(cr, uid, result, ['res_id'])['res_id']
    result = act_obj.read(cr, uid, imd_id)
    result['res_id'] = list_ids
    return result

def create_invoice(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    context = context or {}
    wizard_brw = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    inv_id = context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise osv.except_osv(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(cr, uid, ids, wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id, context)
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window(cr, uid, ids, [inv_id],
                                'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

These methods should read an invoice (previously selected on a pop-up window), then on button click, rewrite this invoice as a cancelled one with the "PAPEL ANULADO" on the invoice name. The method `create_invoice` calls another method called `action_invoice_create`.

This is the migrated method:

```
@api.multi
def action_invoice_create(self, wizard_brw, inv_brw): #cr, uid, ids, wizard_brw, inv_brw, context=None
    """
    If the invoice has control number, this function is responsible for
    passing the bill to damaged paper
    @param wizard_brw: nothing for now
    @param inv_brw: damaged paper
    """
    invoice_line_obj = self.env['account.invoice.line']
    invoice_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
    acc_mv_obj = self.env['account.move']
    acc_mv_l_obj = self.env['account.move.line']
    tax_obj = self.env['account.invoice.tax']
    invoice = {}
    if inv_brw.nro_ctrl:
        invoice.update({
            'name': 'PAPELANULADO_NRO_CTRL_%s' % (
                inv_brw.nro_ctrl and inv_brw.nro_ctrl or ''),
            'state': 'paid',
            'tax_line': [],
        })
    else:
        raise UserError(
            _('Validation error!'),
            _("You can run this process just if the invoice have Control"
              " Number, please verify the invoice and try again."))
    invoice_obj.write([inv_brw.id], invoice) #cr, uid, [inv_brw.id], invoice, context=context
    for line in inv_brw.invoice_line:
        invoice_line_obj.write(
            [line.id],
            {'quantity': 0.0, 'invoice_line_tax_id': [],
             'price_unit': 0.0}) #cr, uid, context=context

    tax_ids = self.env['account.tax'].search([]) # cr, uid, [], context=context
    tax = tax_obj.search([('invoice_id', '=', inv_brw and inv_brw.id)]) # cr, uid, contet=context
    if tax:
        tax_obj.write(tax[0], {'invoice_id': []}) #cr, uid, tax[0], {'invoice_id': []}, context=context
    tax_obj.create({
        'name': 'SDCF',
        'tax_id': tax_ids and tax_ids[0],
        'amount': 0.00,
        'tax_amount': 0.00,
        'base': 0.00,
        'account_id': inv_brw.company_id.acc_id.id,
        'invoice_id': inv_brw and inv_brw.id}, {}) #cr ,uid, was first
    move_id = inv_brw.move_id and inv_brw.move_id.id

    if move_id:
        acc_mv_obj.button_cancel([inv_brw.move_id.id]) #cr, uid, [inv_brw.move_id.id], context=context
        acc_mv_obj.write([inv_brw.move_id.id],{'ref': 'Damanged Paper'}) #cr, uid, [inv_brw.move_id.id],{'ref': 'Damanged Paper'}, context=context
        acc_mv_l_obj.unlink([i.id for i in inv_brw.move_id.line_id]) #cr, uid was first
    return inv_brw.id
```

I'm actually not quite sure if this should be `@api.multi` I think it should be `@api.model` although I'm not really sure.

Anyways, when I click on `create_invoice` method it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_invoice_nro_ctrl.py", line 134, in create_invoice
'action_invoice_tree1', 'account') 
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_invoice_nro_ctrl.py", line 106, in new_open_window
imd_id = mod_obj.browse(result, ['res_id'])
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4755, in browse
return self._browse(ids, self.env, prefetch)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4742, in _browse
prefetch[cls._name].update(ids)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

The errors are on this line `imd_id = mod_obj.browse(result, ['res_id'])` and this one `return self.new_open_window([inv_id], 'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')`

Before, `imd_id` was using `read()` I've changed it to `browse()` but still same error.

I hope I've explained myself.

If You need further info, please let me know.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also noticed your write syntax is Off tax_obj.write({'invoice_id': False]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of things to do here, i will work the method from top to bottom:

Wrong

```py
invoice_obj.write([inv_brw.id], invoice)
```

Right, you can use ORM methods directly on `RecordSet`s

```py
inv_brw.write(invoice)  # maybe rename invoice to invoice_values
```

Wrong

```py
for line in inv_brw.invoice_line:
    invoice_line_obj.write(
        [line.id],
        {'quantity': 0.0, 'invoice_line_tax_id': [],
         'price_unit': 0.0}) #cr, uid, context=context
```

Right, you can use ORM methods directly on `RecordSet`s and if there are more than one record but all values to write are the same, use a write for all records at once:

```py
inv_brw.invoice_line_ids.write({  # lines field was renamed
    'quantity': 0.0,
    'invoice_line_tax_id': [],
    'price_unit': 0.0
})
```

Wrong

```py
tax_ids = self.env['account.tax'].search([]) # cr, uid, [], context=context
tax = tax_obj.search([('invoice_id', '=', inv_brw and inv_brw.id)]) # cr, uid, contet=context
if tax:
    tax_obj.write(tax[0], {'invoice_id': []}) #cr, uid, tax[0], {'invoice_id': []}, context=context
tax_obj.create(values)  # shortened
```

I think it's dangerous to use the "first" tax in the system. But yes, it's not your module. But why not just delete the old invoice tax entries? And why should there be an invoice tax entry, if the invoice lines have no taxes set anymore? Better:

```py
taxes = self.env['account.tax'].search([])  # RecordSets!
invoice_taxes = tax_obj.search(
    [('invoice_id', '=', inv_brw and inv_brw.id)]).unlink()
# tax_obj.create(values)  # not necessary
```

Wrong

```py
move_id = inv_brw.move_id and inv_brw.move_id.id

if move_id:
    acc_mv_obj.button_cancel([inv_brw.move_id.id]) #cr, uid, [inv_brw.move_id.id], context=context
    acc_mv_obj.write([inv_brw.move_id.id],{'ref': 'Damanged Paper'}) #cr, uid, [inv_brw.move_id.id],{'ref': 'Damanged Paper'}, context=context
    acc_mv_l_obj.unlink([i.id for i in inv_brw.move_id.line_id]) #cr, uid was first
```

Right, just use the new API possibilities:

```py
move = inv_brw.move_id
if move:
    move.button_cancel()
    move.ref = 'Damanged Paper'
    move.line_ids.unlink()  # field for the move lines was renamed
```

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a browse record you do not pass the fields that you are wishing to obtain.

```
ids = [6]
rec = self.env['your.model'].browse(ids)['field_name']
```